# Do Lenovo Thinkpads recognize power banks as a different power source than AC?

Tags: battery

If I connect a genuine Lenovo power bank to a Thinkpad (with non-removable internal battery), will the laptop charge the internal battery as if it were connected through a charger to a wall plug?

To charge a battery with another battery, it seems a waste of resources to me.

If it's not automatic, it's there any way of turning the battery off, when you are connected to a power bank?

Comment: I'd imagine it'd work like an AC adapter if USB (C?) charging is supported: if battery depleted charge that up while also providing AC/running power to PC; when battery fully charge solely provide AC power to PC. Might help if you indicate the model of laptop, the model of power bank, & the type of connection from power bank to laptop

Comment: Waste of resources, maybe, but its an easy way to get hot swappable power I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you attach a Lenovo Power Pack, it will recharge the battery in the ThinkPad, unless you remove the battery. Power pack manufacturers are rarely concerned with inefficiencies and are much more responsive to making sure you have power when you need it.